# Continues crawl and Incremental crawl not searching list items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

Continues crawl and Incremental crawl not searching list items.
only full crawl is able to search the list items. please help with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at the crawl log for errors? Did you search for the particular item in the crawl log after creating a new one, verifying Continuous Crawl is running?

Comment: no related crawl errors found and I tried search after one day from the insertion of item still it has the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. If you have re-created search service application or running the crawl for first time, it will perform full crawl. I will suggest to let full crawl complete and then try scheduling continuous or incremental crawl.

Regards,
Simran

Comment: This is not newly created search service or altered search service. it's running for a long time. Now user observed that only full crawling is attracting the new items. continues and incremental crawling not finding new items. full crawling running weekly once.